# PyQt: How to switch widgets in QStackedWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer, qstackedwidget

I have two buttons (*wgtbtnA* & *wgtbtnB*) placed on two different pages (*page1* and *page2*, respectively) inside a parent object (objectName: *stackedWidget*). My dilemma is this: when I run the code, the arrows don't display in PyQt. Why? How do I alternate from page1 to page2 and vice-versa?

Here is an image of runtime, which conveys what I am asking for:

[image: btnwgtB]

Qt Designer:

[image: btnwgtA]

I'd like to keep those small back arrows.

Below is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'stackedWidget.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import os


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(512, 304)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.stackedWidget = QtGui.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 60, 161, 121))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("stackedWidget"))
        self.page = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page"))
        self.wgtMainWindow = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page)
        self.wgtMainWindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 75, 23))
        self.wgtMainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("wgtMainWindow"))
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page_2"))
        self.wgtbtnB = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page_2)
        self.wgtbtnB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 75, 23))
        self.wgtbtnB.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("wgtbtnB"))
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 512, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.wgtMainWindow.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Widget A", None))
        self.wgtbtnB.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Widget B", None))


class ControlMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ControlMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mySW = ControlMainWindow()
    mySW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the buttons to change the page: `{your QPushButton}.clicked.connect(lambda: {your QStackedWidget}.setCurrentIndex({another page}))`

By Example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'stackedWidget.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(512, 304)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.stackedWidget = QtGui.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 60, 161, 121))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("stackedWidget"))
        self.page = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page"))
        self.wgtMainWindow = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page)
        self.wgtMainWindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 75, 23))
        self.wgtMainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("wgtMainWindow"))
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page_2"))
        self.wgtbtnB = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page_2)
        self.wgtbtnB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 75, 23))
        self.wgtbtnB.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("wgtbtnB"))
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 512, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.wgtMainWindow.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Widget A", None))
        self.wgtbtnB.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Widget B", None))


class ControlMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ControlMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.wgtbtnB.clicked.connect(lambda : self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.ui.wgtMainWindow.clicked.connect(lambda : self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mySW = ControlMainWindow()
    mySW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Start app:

[image]

after clicked button:

[image]

after clicked another button:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the two arrows you see in the designer ( in your message below) don't carry over to your application, its a function in the designer so you can switch between them easily

Comment: @ekhumoro : What if you're restricted by the amount you can add. It wouldn't let me add more than 2 images in my original post due to the fact that I'm new. Not trying to be disputatious; however, it's hard to provide specificity and clarity, when your limited in what you can add to prove those point. Ergo, I apologize for my nescience. Perhaps, you have an alternative solution for these cases? If so, I would love to hear. Best Regards, Jeremy

Comment: @JeremyStiefel. Edit your question anyway: someone with the necessary rep can fix the links later on. You're only limited in what you can do by because you haven't got enough rep: so the simple solution is to just [get more rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 1):

To implement your arrows from one screen to the next you just need to propagate those arrows making sure that they appear in each view -- now this can easily be done via code cannot say how difficult it might be in the designer.  Here is a example that does something like what you might be wanting.

```
from sys  import exit as sysExit

from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Win1Disply(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QFrame.__init__(self)

        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.setLineWidth(0.2)
        # -------
        self.Cntnr = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Cntnr.addWidget(QTextEdit('This is Window 1 with whatever contents you want'))
        self.Win1Btn = QPushButton('>>')
        self.Win1Btn.clicked.connect(parent.RightArrow)
        self.Cntnr.addWidget(self.Win1Btn)
        self.Cntnr.addStretch(1)
        # -------
        self.setLayout(self.Cntnr)

class Win2Disply(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QFrame.__init__(self)

        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.setLineWidth(0.2)
        # -------
        self.Cntnr = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Cntnr.addWidget(QTextEdit('This is Window 2 with whatever contents you want'))
        self.Win1Btn = QPushButton('>>')
        self.Win1Btn.clicked.connect(parent.RightArrow)
        self.Cntnr.addWidget(self.Win1Btn)
        self.Cntnr.addStretch(1)
        # -------
        self.setLayout(self.Cntnr)

class OptionButtons(QToolButton):
# Class OptionButtons ("Text", Connector) inherits from QToolButton
    def __init__(self, Text, Connector):
        QToolButton.__init__(self)

        self.setText(Text)
        self.setStyleSheet("font: bold;color: blue;height: 55px;width: 55px;")
        self.setIconSize(QSize(32,32))
        self.clicked.connect(Connector)

############################## Settings Class ##############################
class OptionSettings(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        line = QFrame()
        line.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
        line.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)

        self.btnWin1 = OptionButtons('Win One', self.ShowWindow1)
        self.btnWin2 = OptionButtons('Win Two', self.ShowWindow2)
      # Vertical Box for Buttons *************************************
        self.UpLeft  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.UpLeft.addWidget(self.btnWin1)
        self.UpLeft.addWidget(self.btnWin2)
        self.UpLeft.addStretch(1)
  # Display Area on Right
      # Widget Flip Display ******************************************
        self.UpRite   = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Contents = QStackedWidget()
        self.Contents.addWidget(QTextEdit('Nothing Selected'))
        self.Contents.addWidget(Win1Disply(self))
        self.Contents.addWidget(Win2Disply(self))
        self.Contents.addWidget(QTextEdit('Settings Saved'))
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.UpRite.addWidget(self.Contents)

  # Button and Display Area on Top
        self.Upper = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Upper.addLayout(self.UpLeft)
        self.Upper.addLayout(self.UpRite)
  # Save and Cancel Area on Bottom
        self.btnSave = QPushButton("Save")
        self.btnSave.clicked.connect(self.SaveSettings)
        self.btnCncl = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.btnCncl.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.Lower   = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Lower.addStretch(1)
        self.Lower.addWidget(self.btnSave)
        self.Lower.addWidget(self.btnCncl)
  # Entire Options Window Layout
        self.OuterBox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.OuterBox.addLayout(self.Upper)
        self.OuterBox.addLayout(self.Lower)
        self.setLayout(self.OuterBox)
        self.setWindowTitle('Settings')
        #Geometry(Left, Top, Width, Hight)
        self.setGeometry(250, 250, 550, 450)
        self.setModal(True)
        self.exec()

    def ShowWindow1(self):
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def ShowWindow2(self):
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(2)

    def SaveSettings(self):
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(3)

    def RightArrow(self):
        if self.Contents.currentIndex() == 1:
           self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(2)
        else:
           self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(1)

class CenterPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        CntrPane = QTextEdit('Center Panel is Placed Here')

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(CntrPane)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

class MenuToolBar(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)
        self.MainWin = MainWin
        self.MainMenu = MainWin.menuBar()

        self.WndowMenu  = self.MainMenu.addMenu('Windows')

        self.OptnAct = QAction('Options', self)
        self.OptnAct.setStatusTip('Open the Options Window')
        self.OptnAct.triggered.connect(MainWin.ShowOptions)

        self.WndowMenu.addAction(self.OptnAct)

        self.InitToolBar(MainWin)

    def InitToolBar(self, MainWin):
        self.mainToolBar = MainWin.addToolBar("Quick Access")

        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.OptnAct)

class UI_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI_MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')

      # Left, Top, Width, Height
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 550, 550)

        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        self.MenuToolBar = MenuToolBar(self)

    def ShowOptions(self):
        self.Options = OptionSettings(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp = QApplication([])

    MainGui = UI_MainWindow()
    MainGui.show()

    sysExit(MainApp.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need arrows in your stacked widget, another solution is to implement your own "Promoted Widget": it allows you to create your design with custom widgets, that might extend the basic widgets provided by Qt. You won't be able to interact with your own implementation in Designer, but you'll get the result once you run your program.

This is the procedure: create your own subclass of the widget you want to extend, define your custom methods or override existing ones (remember that some private methods require a specific return value type, check the documentation).
It's usually better to save the subclass(es) you created in a separate files.
Then, in Designer add the widget you need (in this case, StackedWidget), right click on it and select "Promote to..."; in the dialog that will be shown, type the subclass name you created in the "Promoted class name" field (in the example below, it will be "StackedWidgetWithArrowButtons") and the file that contains it in the "header file" field: it will be treated as a python import, so *do not* add the trailing ".py" and remember that if you saved it in a subdirectory you'll need the full "module" path, for example "mysubclasses.customstackwidget", if the file is "customstackwidget" in the "mysubclasses" directory.
Save the ui, compile it and run the program.

```
class StackedWidgetWithArrowButtons(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QStackedWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.backwardButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.backwardButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowLeft))
        self.backwardButton.setMaximumSize(24, 24)
        self.backwardButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.forwardButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.forwardButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowRight))
        self.forwardButton.setMaximumSize(24, 24)
        self.forwardButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.currentChanged.connect(self.checkSwitchButtons)

    def checkSwitchButtons(self):
        self.forwardButton.setEnabled(self.currentIndex() < self.count() - 1)
        self.backwardButton.setEnabled(self.currentIndex() > 0)

    def addWidget(self, widget):
        # this is a private method of QStackedWidget that is called when 
        # the ui is being built by the program, we just implement it 
        # to ensure that the buttons are correctly enabled;
        # the index *has* to be returned
        index = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget.addWidget(self, widget)
        self.checkSwitchButtons()
        return index

    def removeWidget(self, widget):
        # not necessary, but in case you want to remove widgets in the 
        # future, it will check buttons again
        index = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget.removeWidget(self, widget)
        self.checkSwitchButtons()
        return index

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # due to the way QStackedWidget is implemented, children widgets
        # that are not in its layout might not receive mouse events,
        # but we just need to track clicks so this is enough
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            if event.pos() in self.backwardButton.geometry():
                self.setCurrentIndex(self.currentIndex() - 1)
            elif event.pos() in self.forwardButton.geometry():
                self.setCurrentIndex(self.currentIndex() + 1)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # the base class resizeEvent *has* to be called, otherwise 
        # you could encounter problems with children widgets
        QtWidgets.QStackedWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)

        # now ensure that the buttons are always placed on the top
        # right corner; this positioning is completely manual and you
        # have to take button sizes in consideration to avoid 
        # overlapping buttons; obviously you can place them wherever
        # you want.
        self.forwardButton.move(self.rect().right() - self.forwardButton.width(), 0)
        self.backwardButton.move(self.forwardButton.x() - self.backwardButton.width(), 0)
```

If you don't want buttons (or you don't like the way they appear) you could implement your own paintEvent. In this case I created small triangles using QPolygons.

```
class StackedWidgetWithTriangles(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QStackedWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.backwardRect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 16, 16)
        self.forwardRect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 16, 16)
        self.forwardArrow = QtGui.QPolygon([QtCore.QPoint(-6, -6), QtCore.QPoint(6, 0), QtCore.QPoint(-6, 6)])
        self.backwardArrow = QtGui.QPolygon([QtCore.QPoint(6, -6), QtCore.QPoint(-6, 0), QtCore.QPoint(6, 6)])

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            if event.pos() in self.backwardRect:
                self.setCurrentIndex(self.currentIndex() - 1)
            elif event.pos() in self.forwardRect:
                self.setCurrentIndex(self.currentIndex() + 1)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QStackedWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)
        self.forwardRect.moveLeft(self.rect().right() - self.forwardRect.width())
        self.backwardRect.moveLeft(self.forwardRect.x() - self.forwardRect.width())

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
        # set colors according to the possibility of going back or forward,
        # showing a "disabled" arrow whenever it's not possible
        if self.currentIndex() > 0:
            qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.darkGray)
            qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        else:
            qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.lightGray)
            qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        qp.drawPolygon(self.backwardArrow.translated(self.backwardRect.center()))
        if self.currentIndex() < self.count() - 1:
            qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.darkGray)
            qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        else:
            qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.lightGray)
            qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        qp.drawPolygon(self.forwardArrow.translated(self.forwardRect.center()))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have no logic in your `ControlMainWindow` class to switch between your widgets. (also i don't see any arrow widgets for switching) you'll need to add a listener to your `QTbuttons` in your main class like below to execute your logic:

```
yourQTbutton.itemClicked.connect(self.functioWithUIchangingLogic)
```

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more specific. I know how to connect signals and slots. My issue is, where do the pyqt auto-formatted arrows go. Usually, there are two black arrows in the top right-hand corner of the stackedWidgets.

Comment: Are you using QT designer to create the UI? if so the two arrows you see in the designer don't carry over to your application, its a function in the designer so you can switch between them easily

Comment: Got it. So there is no way to programmatically carry them over, correct?